# Passing user data via jQuery AJAX post - Need escaping?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form where users are going to enter some details and I am wanting to post it via `AJAX`; the code I am using to do this would be something like the below..

```
var comments = $('#comments').val(); // User Data

// Set file to get results from..
var loadUrl = "ajax_files/leave_comments.php";

// Set parameters
var dataObject = { comments: comments };

// Run request

getAjaxData(loadUrl, dataObject, 'POST', 'html')

    .done(function(response) {

        // do stuff

    })

    .fail(function() {
        // show error
    });

// End

function getAjaxData(loadUrl, dataObject, action, type) {

    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: action,
        url: loadUrl,
        data: dataObject,
        dataType: type
    });    

}
```

Now, I'm wondering since I don't know what the user is going to enter, do I need to do any manipulation of the data before passing it to jQuery as a data parameter?

Secondly, when I get back this data from jQuery in the `leave_comments.php` file via the `$_POST` variable, will I need to do anything to it?

Comment: why not test it? see what happens when you enter data into the comments field...

Comment: No, you don't need to do anything with the data on the clientside, but always validate the data on the serverside for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the user data contain ' or "\" character. Try to replace before sending them in ajax request.

```
    var comments = $('#comments').val();
    comments = comments .replace(/\\/g, '?');
    comments = comments .replace(/'/g, "\\'");
```